# Updating angular date by repeating event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an end date that a user can enter a date to end an scheduled event. However, I want a user to be able to type in a number of times an event can repeat before it ends. For example, if they say they want it to repeat weekly, for 4 weeks, then I want to be able to calculate the end date, and update that value. I'm actually not quite sure how I should even approach this being relatively new to angular.

http://jsfiddle.net/rXHzc/

I was thinking something like this?

```
function EventEditCtrl($scope) {
    init();

    function init() {
        $scope.event = {
            ActiveEndTimeDate: '',
            Occurrences: '',
            Repeated: ''
        }
    }

    $scope.updateEndDate = function () {
        //update event?
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to calculate the end date and assign it to the model. The hard part is doing date math in JavaScript. You can use a library like momentjs to simplify things...

```
$scope.updateEndDate = function () {
    var endDate = moment().add($scope.event.Repeated, parseInt($scope.event.Occurrences));
    $scope.event.ActiveEndTimeDate = endDate.format('YYYY/MM/DD');
};
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cxtNp/

This approach requires the use of `ngChange` to monitor changes to form values and trigger the update. It relies on having `ngChange` applied to all the places a change can be triggered and leaks a bit too much logic into the markup. A cleaner approach would be to trigger the change when the model changes.

One way to do this is using a watch...

```
$scope.$watch('[event.Repeated, event.Occurrences]', function () {
    var endDate = moment().add($scope.event.Repeated, parseInt($scope.event.Occurrences));
    $scope.event.ActiveEndTimeDate = endDate.format('YYYY/MM/DD');
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c92ud/